# Super speed human to bird survival

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science

Assuming I would be a superhuman going 500km/h, but keeping my human reflexes and without taking into account the air friction.

Now, assuming I would encounter a Pidgeon going my way at about 20km/h. I do not have time to avoid it, and we are going in a straight line.

Would I survive if I took it :
- directly to the throat ?
- with my elbow pointed to the bird (and my throat behind my arm) ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Comment: FWIW, the modern spelling is ["pigeon"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169985/is-pidgeon-a-correct-alternate-spelling-of-pigeon), unless you mean [this Pidgeon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Pidgeon). ;)

Comment: Our "be stupidly nice to new members policy" prevents me from saying all the sarcastic things I want to about this question, but it's a prime example of a question where sarcasm should be encouraged, not discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

You can view this as an inelastic collision with the pigeon. This means conservation of momentum holds true but not energy conservation. Now let $M$ and $V$ be your mass, respectively your velocity and $m$ and $v$ the pigeon’s mass, respectively velocity. Let further be $u$ the velocity after the collision which will be the same for you and the pigeon since you are sticking together (inelastic collision). Then, by conservation by momentum
$$MV+mv=(M+m)u.$$
Let now assume $M=70\,\text{kg}$ and $m=0.5\,\text{kg}$, then with $V=500\,\text{km/h}$ and $v=-20\,\text{km/h}$
$$u=\frac{MV+mv}{M+m}=496\,\text{km/h}.$$ The energy you have to absorb is the change in kinetic energy
$$\Delta E = \frac1 2 MV^2 - \frac1 2 Mu^2=\frac1 2M(V^2-u^2)=12.8\,\text{kJ}.$$
The change in momentum is
$$\Delta p=MV-Mu=280\,\text{kg$\,$km/h} = 77.8\,\text{kg$\,$m/s}.$$
Let us assume the collision takes $\Delta t=0.1\,\text{s}$ as an upper bond. Then the force 
$$F=\frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t} = 778\,\text{N}.$$ This equivalent to placing approximately $79\,\text{kg}$ on your throat. Hence I think the collision will likely be deathly.